# Is there a word that could mean both serious and humorous?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm creating a project on character traits, and the person that I'm writing about is funny yet serious. I didn't know if there was a word for that, so I'm asking for help.

Comment: funny and serious are kinda antonyms... I don't know how one can be serious and funny at the same time

Comment: Possibly [**tragicomic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tragicomic).

Comment: We say that someone has a **dry sense of humor** if they say things that seem very serious on the surface, but are funny when you think about them for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe here's what you are looking for -

> **Facetious**
> <sub>adjective</sub>
>
> : treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humor;
> flippant.
>
> *a facetious remark*
>
> (From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/facetious))

For example -

> Jacky was being *facetious* when she said, "Yes, let's all go to Iraq
> for my birthday party!"

Jacky is trying to sound serious while saying this, but it is not supposed to be taken seriously; it's supposed to be humorous. So basically, you can say that she is being serious and humorous at the same time.

Comment: 'Droll' is a hypernym, 'funny in an unusual way'.

Answer (score 5):

You might call this person

## **Deadpan**.

[Deadpan](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/deadpan) means "without emotion," but the most often-used context is "deadpan humor" which is humor delivered in a serious manner.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **seriocomic**.

- [adj] Both serious and comic.
- [adj] Having both serious and comedic qualities or tendencies.

Comment: You should include the source of the definition.

Comment: Sounds like Spanglish.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with finding the right description of this myself.

When you say something that is factually true but fact is not the purpose for saying it.... but maybe it is.

Three words come to mind.
Facetious ideas full of double entendres and puns all rolled into one!

Is there a word for that?.... it was a facetious comment but not necessarily..... there are multiple meanings for that statement but not necessarily.... and the pun was intended but not necessarily...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Sarcastic.** I am a master at talking trash to someone about themselves and them laugh as I make "jokes" , but in all actuality I am being serious.